# Windows 8 Metro open Local files (.html)

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I want to open a local html file from windows 8 metro (javascript ) App.
I tried doing it the way : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701484.aspx . It works fine as soon as i keep giving the actual http address but as soon as i replace them with my local file path , the success return is false everytime.

Any help ??

Comment: From the page you link to: `You cannot use this method to launch a URI in the local zone. For example, apps cannot use the file:/// protocol to access files on the local computer. Instead, you must use the Storage APIs to access files.`

Comment: @Pekka : can you provide link with some documentation or perhaps with some example.

Comment: Not really - I don't know anything about Metro. But your page contains a link to documentation abut Storage APIs

Comment: I didn't find any Storage APIs that could launch the local files. They are just for reading/writing and other things.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the StorageAPIs and read all the HTML in a file. Then create a DOM element and set its innerHTML. (This is much  easier if you use jQuery to manipulate the DOM).

I've got an example of something similar - where I read files from the app's local storage directory, and show the HTML in a web browser control. The example is in C# / XAML, but a similar logic can be used (without the need for a web browser control - since your app would be running inside a host that can directly show HTML like a browser):

http://krishnanadiminti.blogspot.com.au/2012/09/howto-provide-in-app-help-using-html.html

Comment: Thanks. But my task is just the opposite . I have created the html from DOM itself and now i have to launch it in an external browser.

Comment: Ok, so to launch it in an external browser you need a URL that the browser can hit. Perhaps you could host a service that returns the HTML?